# Insert a new span into an existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in my code:

```
<span class="current">Option 1$ 1,025.64</span>
```

and I'd like to change it with jQuery to look like:

```
<span class="current">Option 1 <span class="unit-price">$ 1,025.64</span></span>
```

Basically I want to insert a new span into an existing.

On the top of that my probelm is that I have more `class="current"` in my code. These are **nice-select** dropdown lists but some of them will have price in its content which has to be formatted when it is active and shown in dropdown. Therefore I need this trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
 $currentText = $('.current').text().split('$');
 $currentText[1] = '<span class="unit-price">$' + $currentText[1] + '</span>';
 $currentText = $currentText.join('');
 $('.current').html($currentText);
```

This will return:

```
<span class="current">Option 1<span class="unit-price">$ 1,025.64</span></span>
```